# Why did Travis miss these shots?

Tags: plot-explanation, taxi-driver

In Scorsese's Taxi Driver, Travis Bickle is shown to be a competent shooter, having regularly practiced in gun ranges. He was also a former Marine who was honorably discharged after serving in the Vietnam war. When he saw a convenient store cashier being robbed, he was able to fatally shoot the attacker without being noticed.

However, when Travis attempts to save Iris from the prostitution ring, he shoots 'Sport' in the waist, which left him able to walk and retaliate fire. He also shoots the hotel owner twice in the arm.

Why did Travis fail to kill those two people, when he's portrayed to be a good shot? Travis was also able to fatally wound Sport across the hallway when he retaliated, and managed a headshot for the mafioso he killed. Did he intentionally miss to show mercy?

Comment: Since I don't know of a canonical answer, I'll just suggest that even a perfect shot is not always perfect.  It's perfectly feasible to assume there were reasons for his inaccuracies, including nerves and movement of both the target and himself.